# Download file from a path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, mern

I am trying to create a download link in a React front end where the user will be clicking a button and a file will be downloaded.

To acheive this, I am trying to pass the file path inside a JS function and inside the function I want to call an API endpoint with that path, and the api will return me the file.

Now, for some reason, the code I am writing is not working. Kindly help me to rectify my mistake.

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import {
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Typography,
  Table,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableBody,
} from "@mui/material";
import Download from './Download';
import FileDownload from "js-file-download";

export default function Classroomtest() {
  const uid = localStorage.getItem("uniqueid");
  const [assignments, setassignments] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/app/get-my-assignments/${uid}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setassignments(res.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const view = (path) =>{
     //Nothing is coming here
          }

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Paper
        sx={{
          padding: 3,
          margin: 1,
        }}
      >
        <TableContainer
          component={Paper}
          sx={{
            margin: "10px",
            width: "97%",
          }}
        >
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 100 }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="right">Topic</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Due</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Action</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Delete</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>

            {assignments?.data?.myassignments.map((item) => (
              <TableBody key={item._id}>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.assignmentname}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{moment.utc(item.duedate).format("MMMM,DD")}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                  <button type="button" onClick={view(item.assignmentfilepath)}>Download</button>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Java</TableCell>
              </TableBody>
            ))}
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Example of a file path returned is : uploads\user-1638470921415.pdf

Comment: It would be easier for us if you named the functions/objects you refer to when you mentioned them in your question. For example, what is the name of the JS function you mentioned in your code?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was the view function.. But I solved the problem is using state hook and got my results. Thank you for viewing my issue. Cheers!!